# General configuration for KendoUI MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

All girds in application are `Sortable` , `Pageable` and `Scrollable`. Is it possible to create a general configuration for Kendo UI for setting these properties in asp.net mvc projects ?

Update: one solution is using [extension helper](http://www.telerik.com/forums/define-a-custom-html-kendo-extension-helper) for Kendo UI

Any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no other solution . If you want to add telerik in your existing project you need to use the extension . But if you are creating new project then when you click at new project then in the list of application types from where you select **ASP.NET MVC web application** , you need to select **Telerik ASP.NET MVC application** .